# Make Irfanview default program for .JPG files

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I want to use Irfanview to view **.jpg** files.  I have gone through the 
Windows 10 default program procedures, but Windows doesn't show Irfanview as a program I can select.

How do I make Irfanview my default program for .jpg files?

Answer (score 3):

1) Find a jpeg file and right click it, select 'Choose another app'

[image]

2) Select the "Always us this app to open .jpg files" checkbox

3) "More Apps' and then, if your program is not listed, select "Look for another app on this PC"

[image]

4) Navigate to the executable for your file and select it.

After this .jpg files should open with your preferred program. Let me know if you run in to other issues.

Comment: Windows 10 won't show Irfanview as an option, so i can't select it.

Comment: @alleyrunner When you press 'Look for another app on this PC' you should get a windows explorer folder to pop up, go to here: C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView and look for the executable - it should be i_view32.exe then select that. That's how you add it to the windows list of programs.

Comment: @alleyrunner let me know if you can get it from there or where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Does not work as it never opens an image with Irfanview despite all settings.

Comment: No longer works in windows 10 - the checkbox is now missing. Grr.

Answer (score 3):

I only could change it in Control Panel - Default apps